# for loop to print out multiple arrays with similar names

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, console.log

I've got multiple arrays, like so:

```
bugNames0 = ["wasp", "roach", "stinkbug", "mantis"];
bugNames1 = ["hornet", "beetle", "ant", "termite"];
bugNames2 = ["gnat", "fly", "grub", "chigger"];
bugNames3 = ["flea", "bed-bug","maggots", "cricket"];
```

Next up I have this for loop:

```
function bugLoop() {
for (var i=0; i < 4 ; i++){
    console.log(bugNames0[i]);
    }
}
```

That will successfully print the first array to console, or each individually if I manually update the number in the array's name.

But is there a way to do something more like this? This following code bit doesn't work, but I hope it explains what I am trying to do:

```
for (var i=0, j=0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(bugNames(i)[j]);
    }
}
```

Here i represents the bugName#, which I would like to get to update through 0 - 3 as the loop runs, printing out only the first option of each array represented by j.

Goal outcome printed to console would be:

```
"wasp", "hornet", "gnat", "flea"
```

Or something like that.

If possible I would like solutions only using vanilla JS as I'm working on a project (self assigned exercise) where I'm trying to complete it using vanilla. Kind of a force myself to get the know the language better exercise.

(Also, I've only been coding for 4 months, so sorry if this is a noob question. I couldn't find the answer online anywhere, just lots of loops on printing out arrays normally.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store all four arrays into one larger array (each bugNames array would simply be an element within this larger array). Let's call it `bugCollection`:

```
bugCollection = [["wasp", "roach", "stinkbug", "mantis"], ["hornet", "beetle", "ant", "termite"], ["gnat", "fly", "grub", "chigger"], ["flea", "bed-bug","maggots", "cricket"]]
```

Alternately, you could keep your variable storage of these arrays and say:

`bugCollection = [bugNames0, bugNames1, bugNames2, bugNames3]`

Then you could iterate through the larger array, logging out the index at each.

```
var oneFromEachArray = function(index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bugCollection.length; i++) {
        console.log(bugCollection[i][index]);
    }
}

oneFromEachArray(0) // Console logs 'wasp', 'hornet', 'gnat', 'flea'
```

Comment: It took me a bit to realize that what you and AnthonyDJ were recommending essentially the same thing. However, you went into more depth to explain it. Thanks for doing that, I appreciate it (and needed it to fully wrap my head around the concept).

Comment: Happy to hear you found value out of it!

Answer (score 2):

If you can store your arrays within an array, that would be a better option.

For instance:

```
bugNames[0] = ["wasp", "roach", "stinkbug", "mantis"];
bugNames[1] = ["hornet", "beetle", "ant", "termite"];
bugNames[2] = ["gnat", "fly", "grub", "chigger"];
bugNames[3] = ["flea", "bed-bug","maggots", "cricket"];
```

Then you can loop through the `bugNames` array normally.

Comment: This actually works well. You and rkho both showed two different ways of sticking arrays within arrays. He went into more depth about how the function works, but this way of organizing the arrays looks wonderfully clean. It's definitely a habit I'm going to start using from now on!

(I'm going to mark his as the answer here because of the full explanation. I figure since this is a beginner's question it would be good to have that in case anyone else comes across this thread.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try eval

```
for (var j=0; j < 4 ; j++){
    for (var i=0; i < 4 ; i++){
        eval("console.log(bugNames" + j + "[i]);");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually having some issues getting this working, though I think I'll play with it some more later to get eval figured out. Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function eval() like this:

```
for (var i=0, j=0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(eval('bugNames' + i)[j]);
}
```

But did you already consider utilizing an array of arrays? Maybe that would be a cleaner way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I actually hadn't considered using an array of arrays, though a couple of other people suggested it and I'm reading up on it now. I've been trying to build a habit of learning to code cleanly, and figured it would better to just make myself aim for clean starting out rather than changing habits later. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can always access your variables using window object. Please use following code to access your variable dynamically.

```
for (var i=0, j=0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(window["bugNames"+i][j]);

}
```

Comment: This actually works very well, and I'm going to save this for future use. Thanks!

Comment: This approach is specially useful, when you have JSON object having dynamic keys. var users = {user1:{name:"Punit"}, user1:{name:"Genko"}}. You cannot access it using users."user"+1. But you can access it like users["user"+1].

Comment: I'm definitely going to use it when I use JSON objects with dynamic keys. Really appreciate the advice :)